# catalina.base path while run service from IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, catalina

I have Hello World web service application based on Jersey in my Eclipse IDE that runs on Windows. Trying to add [Request Dumper Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter). I need to define `CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties` for this purpose. But where is CATALINA_BASE when I run Tomcat from Eclipe IDE. Looks like to editing `C:/tomcat/config/logging.properties` makes no effect, because logs not appear in `C:/tomcat/logs/`

Answer (score 0):

`CATALINA_BASE` is configured in the `Server Locations` section which you can access by double click `Tomcat` in the Servers Tab :

[image]

To set it to be the same as your tomcat server folder , you can choose "Use Tomcat installation".

BTW, you can use `ps -ef | grep java` (For Windows world, it is `tasklist` I think)  to verify what folder is `CATALINA_BASE` refer to after starting the tomcat.

Comment: My `Server Locations` not allows selection. All of them are unchecked and disabled.

Comment: yeah . forget to mention , it is very annoying , I also don't have the idea why it does not allow to modify . I usually delete the server and re-create again such that I can choose that server location options.